# Как увеличить тень в box-shadow только с одной стороны?

Tags: css3, css

Подскажите, как можно растянуть тень только с одной стороны?
но сделать это надо не в ущерб противоложной стороне.
Тоесть при сдвиги в лево, тень справа должна оставаться на месте и не уменьшаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увеличивай и уменьшай Horizontal Length (сдвиг по x) и Vertical Length (сдвиг по y) - получится то, что хочешь. Это первые два значения:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
box-shadow: -5px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

+[CSS generator](http://css3generator.com/) в помощь.